# How to fix the color of the border to one color in colorscale?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to fix one color to the border of the colorscale widget of tkmacosx library: when the window opens the color is blue after interacting with the colorscale the color of the border also change. How can I stop this and fix it to one color?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import ColorVar, Colorscale

win = Tk()
win.geometry('300x200')
var = ColorVar()

entry = Entry(win, fg=var)
entry.pack()

colorscale = Colorscale(win, variable=var, mousewheel=1)
colorscale.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove or hide or change it's color of the borderline as it is just an item of [`Canvas`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and can be accessed by its tag name `"borderline"`. The borderline change its color when a user interacts with the `Colorscale` and when the widget is resized.

To remove the border, you can simply do the following

```py
colorscale.after(100, lambda: colorscale.delete('borderline'))
```

And to hide, all you need to do is to change the state of the borderline to `"hidden"` like the following

```py
colorscale.after(100, lambda: Canvas.itemconfig(
    colorscale, 'borderline', state='hidden'))
```

To change the color of the borderline first, you need to change the color of the borderline by adding `Canvas.itemconfig(self, 'borderline', outline='#8E91F3')` and then dtag the `"borderline"` tag with `Canvas.dtag(self, 'borderline')`.

Use the following `_set_size` function to fix any color of the borderline.

```py
def _set_size(self, evt=None):
    """Internal function."""
    if evt.width == self._size[0] and evt.height == self._size[1]:
        return
    self._size = (evt.width, evt.height)
    self._create_items('create', safe_create=True, avoid=('borderline'))
    self._create_items('check')   # Check and creates a borderline
    Canvas.itemconfig(self, 'borderline', outline='#8E91F3') # Changes the color 
    Canvas.dtag(self, 'borderline')  # Removes "borderline" tag from all matching items.
```

---

Now, you can call any one of the above functions every time the widget resizes. But I would recommend that you rather modify the internal function [`_set_size`](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/blob/b13e7250b2a6a4c311be9e200bc09839dd6aa88d/tkmacosx/colorscale.py#L122) of `Colorscale` than calling anyone of the above functions every time `<Configure>` sequence triggers. So I made a custom class `MyColorscale` which will not show borderline.

```py
class MyColorscale(Colorscale):
    def _set_size(self, evt=None):
        """Internal function."""
        if evt.width == self._size[0] and evt.height == self._size[1]:
            return
        self._size = (evt.width, evt.height)
        self._create_items('create', safe_create=True, avoid=('borderline'))
```

Comment: Thank you Saad! But your answer is completely removing the borderline, i want to fix the color of it to #8E91F3 color. how can i do that?

Comment: @MrCodemaster: You can do that as well, all you have to do is add two lines in your `_set_size` function which first change the color of the border and then `dtag` it so the color won't change when the user interacts with the colorscale.

Comment: Thanks Saad, it is working now! can you please explain what you did at this line self._create_items('check').

Comment: @MrCodemaster: `_create_items` is an internal function used to create items of canvas specifically for the `Colorscale` widget. If you want to see the function itself, you check it [here](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/blob/b13e7250b2a6a4c311be9e200bc09839dd6aa88d/tkmacosx/colorscale.py#L136).